# How do I show the full solution for this?

Tags: parametric

My lecturer gave us a potential bonus to the grade if we can fully solve those equations:
$y^x=9 $
$x^y=8$

easy to see that the value of $x$ and $y$ are $2$ & $3$ but what is the correct full way of showing the solution for that?

appreciate your help geniuses <3

Comment: Please share with us what you tried and what is your level of knowledge.

Comment: Is the only solution? I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

$y^x=9 \Rightarrow x=\frac{ln9}{lny}$ , $x^y=8 \Rightarrow y=\frac{ln8}{lnx}$
Substitute to get $x=\frac{ln9}{ln(\frac{ln8}{lnx})}=\frac{ln9}{ln(ln8)-ln(lnx)} \Rightarrow x(ln(ln8)-ln(lnx))=ln9 \Rightarrow xln(ln8)-xlnln(x)=ln9$
And then well, using Wolframe Alpha to solve the above equation, we get $x=2$. This then implies $2^y=8 \Rightarrow y=3$.

Hope that help!

Comment: I don't think you need Wolframe Alpha to prove uniqueness at this point. The function $x(\ln(\ln(8)-\ln(\ln(x))$ is strictly increasing. Hence there is at most one solution and we already know the solution $x=2$.

Comment: Ah right! Thank you! But the function is strictly decreasing, right?

Comment: You're right, it's decreasing. The argument still works the same though :-)

Comment: I appreciate your effort alot, that helped me much
I just didnt get the last step you did to find x=2
is that some common form ?  xln(ln8)−xlnln(x)=ln9
the alpha site doesnt show me full solution from that stage without paying them ^^

Comment: if you can screen the solution from wolframe alpha site it would be much appreciated!!! TY